# Azure | Terraform not working after couple hours of sitting

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to run an example terraform file, it ran fine a few hours ago but now it won't. I have not touched the computer or terraform since it last ran right using `terraform plan`. I am getting the error below, I did sign back in and that's it.

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.azure: Insufficient configuration data. Please specify either a 'settings_file'
or both a 'subscription_id' and 'certificate'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error mainly caused by the plugins getting downloaded during Terraform init.

There perhaps is a resource or data resource from the older azure (classic) provider. You could check your Terraform Configuration and see if there's any references to the older Azure provider (resource names which use the prefix azure_)

For more information, please refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17469).